# AS3: How can I unzip a zip file to air application folder through my air application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, zip

I have some files and directories structure in my zip folder.
How can I open that zip file and copy it's contain to air application folder through my air application?

I checked some links, but not sure enough, how it works?

It's more like, if I am updating any air application.
Or adding new features to it. So I want to use the contain of the zip to be used.

Actually, I need a walk-through on this. How this can be done?

-Thanks.

Comment: No code shown, reads like a request for a tutorial. [How to ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, but I need someone to help me out of this... Please bare with me.

Comment: Just try something. Find a ZIP library (like **FZIP**) for AS3 that you understand and show code where you try to unzip to application folder. There are examples in the AS3 manual to detect the application folder etc. What is "new features" exactly? It cannot be code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used "airxzip" : https://code.google.com/archive/p/airxzip/ 
Which worked correctly for me on iOs / Windows with large zip file (400-500Mo) and a lots of files in multiple nested directories.

```
var reader:ZipFileReader = new ZipFileReader();
reader.addEventListener(ZipEvent.ZIP_DATA_UNCOMPRESS, zipDataUncompressHandler);
var zipFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('myArchive.zip');
reader.open(zipFile);

var list:Array = reader.getEntries();
// var zipFileCount:int = list.length;

for each(var entry:ZipEntry in list){
    var filename:String = entry.getFilename();

    if(entry.isDirectory()){
        //trace("DIR  --->" + filename);
    }
    else{
        //trace("FILE --->" + filename + "(" + entry.getCompressRate() + ")");
        reader.unzipAsync(entry);
    }
}

private function zipDataUncompressHandler(e:ZipEvent):void {

    var entry:ZipEntry = e.entry;

    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('data' + File.separator + entry.getFilename());
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fs.open(file,FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeBytes(e.data);
    fs.close();

    zipFileWritedCount++;

    // Add a check if all files have been uncompressed, so close the reader and remove the archie
    // if(zipFileWritedCount == zipFileCount)
    //    (e.target as ZipFileReader).close();
    //    var zipFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('versionArchive.zip');
    //    zipFile.deleteFile();
    // }
}
```

Comment: It's a great help for me to understand where I was wrong, Thanks, Guill

Comment: Also like to know, if my zip file contains files and folder. Will maintain the structure?

Comment: Yes file/directory structure will be maintained

Comment: @GuillaumeTRIBUT is there a progress event handler for this library? or at least on finish event? I mean when the whole archive content is uncompressed and saved, i want to shoot a new event.

Answer (score 0):

Saying: "Or adding new features to it" pretty much means you have no experience with this.

Any attempt to update on the fly the code of an installed Ios app will result in that app being disabled completely for security reasons. Moreover those attempts could get you banned from itunes.connect.

There's only one way to update an Ios app and it's by publishing a new version in itnues.

Updating assets on the fly is possible, bitmaps, sounds, etc... as long as they don't contain any code.

No new files can be written in the working application folder for security reasons, they have to be written to the storage folder of the app.

Comment: Ok, but what I mean was, if my app runs with some external swf files for loading the interface with no code on it, can I store or overwrite them with new ones, by extracting these zip file.

Comment: If you pack your app with asset "A", that asset is installed with the app in the app folder, there it can never be overwritten or replaced, You can copy it in the storage folder and load it from there and in that case you can replace it by new ones.

Comment: Here you are, I got that. Now what I am trying, is: I will keep these new files in a zip file. And when I'll click my updated button, which will be in my app, it should able to extract these files to my storage folder. This is where am stuck in. Can you help??

Comment: Being stuck is when you try something and it doesn't work. In your case it's more like you don't know how to do it and you haven't tries anything. Google as3 zip libraries, there are a few and try them.